# Как можно оптимизировать данный код?

Tags: java, оптимизация, if, for

```
public boolean mono(boolean[] data) {
        boolean result = false;
        for (int index = 0; index != data.length; index++) {
            for (int index2 = 0; index2 != data.length; index2++) {
                if (index == index2) continue;
                if (data[index] == data[index2]){
                    return true;
                } else return false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Можно ли обойтись одним циклом for и if?

Comment: Непонятен смысл кода: если значение 1-го индекса массива совпадает со 2-м то возвращаем `true` иначе `false` - какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаток Java, но, похоже, все тело функции можно заменить на такое: `return data[0] == data[1]`. То есть вообще без циклов, и без `if`.

Comment: Для начала нужно убрать ``else return false``. Иначе действительно получается ``return data[0] == data[1]``. Потом нужно разобраться - возращаем значение переменной ``result``? Тогда нужно его где-то изменять. Или возвращаем сразу тру или фалс? Тогда нужно убрать переменную ``result``. А потом нужно выяснить, что должен делать код, и рассказать нам.

Comment: Странный вообще алгоритм, в любом случае, еслимассив будет состоятть из трех элементов и более будет return true

Comment: Если же элементов всего два то и нужно проверить

Comment: {[true],[false],[true]} - true, {[true],[flase],[false]}-true, {[false],[false],[false]}- true

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев А, ну да. :) На самом деле, есть подозрение, что функция задумывалась, как проверяющая, все ли элементы массива одинаковы.

Comment: if(data.length>2) {return true; }else{return data[0]==data[1]}

Answer (score 1):

итак, если код действительно верен, то вот вам упрощение:

```
public boolean mono(boolean[] data) {
    if(data.length > 1)
        return data[0] == data[1];
    else
        return false; 
}
```

P?S?
Когда-то меня друг с филологического просил написать для него программу и дал в качестве примера код старшекурсников (с филологического!!). Программа должна была выводить календарь, при входных параметрах первый день недели, кол-во дней в месяце. Так вот в их коде не было ни 1 цикла. Все было написано printf и if....

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, в логике самой функции ошибка, так как вся суть функции сведется к тому, что будет проверены на сходство 0 и 1 элементы массива. Если они будут равны, то возвратится true иначе false и выполнение функции прекратится. Т.е. если все таки функционал написан верно, то вся задача сводится к проверке кол-ва элементов массива и если оно больше 1, то можно смело сравнивать 0 и 1 элементы, Вы уверены в том, что Вы хотели именно это?